# Connect to Supabase PostgreSQL database with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, arcgis-pro, database

I am trying to connect my PostgreSQL database on supabase.com with ArcGIS Pro and edit data. Only way how I was able to do it was when I've created a new database on the pgAdmin inside supabase connection server. But the data were read only in ArcGIS and the database disappeared in pgAdmin anyway. So this is possibly not an option. How can I connect the default "postgres" database on supabase with ArcGIS?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0, PostgreSQL 14.1 and the database name doesn't contain any special characters or uppercases.  It is just the default postgres database on Supabase.

Comment: It's pretty much *worst* practice to use the `postgres` admin database for **any** user data. PostGIS is *not* supported in `postgres`, either. You need to create a new database (lower case name) with an ownership login role (lower-case as well) before you can start. You also need to use a supported PG release (PG 14 is not supported by Pro 3.0, so it would probably be a late 3.0 or new 3.1 before 14 is supported). The documentation indicates the steps necessary to generate an geodatabase-enabled PG instance.  Note that your directionality is wrong: You connect *to* a database not from it.

Comment: @Vince But how can I create a new database in supabase? It was only possible in pgAdmin and it disappeared in the client after refresh. It was still visible via ArcGIS but the data were read only. And there was no evidence of this new created database in supabase.com website.

Comment: That's a question for Supabase. Still, with a PG 14 instance, it's a non-starter for Pro 3.0.

Comment: 13.6 is the highest supported version  https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/windows/database-requirements-postgresql.htm

Comment: @Mapperz It doesn't work with 3.1 either.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, I have successfully connected to Supabase from QGIS. In my Supabase project, I have a PostgreSQL version 15.x with the latest PostGIS. I was able to create and edit data through this connection.

Though this information may not directly answer your question about connecting from ArcGIS Pro, I thought it could be useful to know about the QGIS workflow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).